# How to update float data with NaN value in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, database, matlab

I've a MATLAB script which calls the [update](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.update.html) function to update a SQL Server database. But when i try to update a float data with a NaN value, i get the following error message:

> Error using database.jdbc.connection/update
> Unable to complete update operation. The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 6 (""): the supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

Note that the related float data can be null.

Comment: NULL: Check if field allow

Comment: And then UPDATE ... SET Some = NULL